# gcc 4.7.1 build ends with undefined reference

Tags: c++, c, gcc, mpfr

I am getting a

> fortran/arith.o: In function `gfc_mpfr_to_mpz(__mpz_struct*,
>   __mpfr_struct*, locus*)': arith.c:(.text+0x1169): undefined reference to`mpfr_get_z_2exp'

from gcc 4.7.1 build process. I am following

[gcc-wiki](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC)

However, I have made a little change to the

download_prequisites

script. And that is I am downloading the latest releases of all the prequisites for gcc where the original one was downloading a bit older ones since the above link was given for gcc 4.6. However, it can not find some symbols related to mpfr library.

A related google search gives me this thread however it also did not help me, maybe someone else could understand that differently than me:

[A similar thread](http://www.spinics.net/lists/gcchelp/msg37496.html)

Any hints on how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Did you get the latest mpfr library and unpack it as a sub dir of gcc. Checkout out http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter05/gcc-pass1.html

Answer (score 0):

I recently built gcc 4.7.1 for Mountain Lion and followed a very nice tutorial of how to do a gcc build.  In it, it describes all the necessary lib compilations, include mpfr, gmp and others.  If you're running linux, I think it will work for you as well, give it a try:

http://solarianprogrammer.com/2012/07/21/compiling-gcc-4-7-1-mac-osx-lion/

Let me know if that helps.